# Replace a certain substring with dashes in betweenn - python

Tags: python, string, replace, substring, hyphenation

Is there any string manipulation in python that can achieves the following input and output?  If i'm going to use regex how would the regex expression look like to replace the substring?

```
#inputs
y = sentence-with-dashes
x = this is a sentence with dashes

#output
z = this is a sentence-with-dashes

#####################################
#sometimes the input is pretty messed up like this
y = sentence-with-dashes
x = this is a sentence-with dashes

#output
z = this is a sentence-with-dashes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
y='sentence-with-dashes'
x='this is a sentence with dashes'
r=re.compile(re.escape(y).replace('\\-','[- ]'))
z=re.sub(r,y,x)
```

this won't touch any hyphens that appear outside the `y` value, if you don't care about this then eumiro's answer is simpler, and doesn't require the use of regex.

Comment: don't forget to add `\b` where appropriate

Comment: That won't work if `y` contains anything with special meaning to regular expressions. Try `r=re.compile(re.escape(y).replace('\\-','[- ]'))` to protect any non alphanumeric characters.

Comment: You missed that the hyphen also gets escaped so you have to escape it in the replace call (so I edited it for you).

Answer (score 1):

If these are the only dashes:

```
z = x.replace('-', ' ').replace(y.replace('-', ' '), y)
```

Comment: This works fine for he OP's example, but I can see it gets fun where `x = 'ooops - a sentence-with dashes'` and the result is `z == 'ooops   a sentence-with-dashes'` (<- there is a double space in there...)...

Comment: @JonClements - yes, that's why I wrote "if these are the only dashes" . With more dashes it does not work properly.